# Create a new array of objects by property value from existing object add existing objects to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops

I have an existing array of objects which share a property titled `type` like so

```
[
 {
   id: 1,
   name: 'a',
   type: 'foo',
 },{
   id: 2,
   name: 'b',
   type: 'bar',
 },{
   id: 3,
   name: 'c',
   type: 'fizz',
 },{
   id: 4,
   name: 'd',
   type: 'foo',
 },
]
```

I need to be able to structure a new array of objects with the existing ones grouped together by `type` like this

```
[
 {
  type: 'foo',
  groups: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'a',
      type: 'foo',
    },{
      id: 4,
      name: 'd',
      type: 'foo',
    },
  ]
 },{
  type: 'bar',
  groups: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'b',
      type: 'bar',
    }
  ]
 },{
  type: 'fizz',
  groups: [
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'c',
      type: 'fizz',
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

this is what I have so far but im not able to create the new array and organize the objects by type, only able to grab the type itself any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Observable.value.map(objects => {
    typesArr = [...new Set(objects.data.map(object => object.type))];
}); /// output = ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the array to a Map, using the `type` as the key. Use `Array.from()` to convert the Map's values iterator to an array:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"a","type":"foo"},{"id":2,"name":"b","type":"bar"},{"id":3,"name":"c","type":"fizz"},{"id":4,"name":"d","type":"foo"}]

const result = Array.from(arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const type = o.type
  if(!acc.has(type)) acc.set(type, { type, groups: [] })
  
  acc.get(type).groups.push(o)
  
  return acc
}, new Map()).values())

console.log(result)
```

To make TS infer the type of the grouped array, infer the type of an item from the original array, and use it to set the type of the Map ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gbwEQEsAm2AXAIwA02YcAtgKbHZzYVQCeADvUdgGYgjYAvmRwFiAJgpU6DAEbNsbTnMRCReQkQDMUml2zAFS-T1wAvM2tGaALLpndCLDif5CAugFgAUD%20MwASShaalQYAApjEB54JABKdAAGL19vUEhYBFoIAFcAG1g0AEEkOFYAOh4EEGpwxARyrPwc4FpwuuBgMhgQONQAPhhMHxgYdOgYfzQQcuMRmFwecIBCOE7ygAs4CEiXOL614HKIWihdzm7MSZdugHNqnPYIIgx3GEE4%20fnD8tvT89ocWWvweT3K7ByEA24V6X28oyyUByCDA8E6PmEMDAtAA7jAALJwdgAHmgCFwYFul2unBeQRC6AA5MZGe47qDnoFgtR0G9BP1wvtygA3OB5HLZQWfVLjEB5WjlPIgW7hLK5ApxIA)):

```
const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"a","type":"foo"},{"id":2,"name":"b","type":"bar"},{"id":3,"name":"c","type":"fizz"},{"id":4,"name":"d","type":"foo"}]

type Item = (typeof arr)[0]

const result = Array.from(arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const type = o.type
  if(!acc.has(type)) acc.set(type, { type, groups: [] })
  
  acc.get(type)!.groups.push(o)
  
  return acc
}, new Map<string, { type: Item['type'], groups: Item[] }>()).values())

console.log(result)
```

Another option is to reduce the array to a map of groups `[type, object]`, and then use `Array.from()` to convert the Map's entries to the required form ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gbwEQEsAm2AXAIwA02YcAtgKbHZzYVQCeADvUdgGYgjYAvmRwFiAJgpU6DAEbNsbTnMRCReQkQDMUml2zAFS-T1wAvM2tGaALLpndCLDif5CAugFgAUD%20MwASShaalQYAApjEB54JABKdAAGL19vUEhYBFoIAFcAG1g0AEEkOFYAOh4EEGpwnxhYhHKs-BzgWnDwuGBgMhgQONQAPhhMeoaYdOgYfzQQcuNxhtwecIBCbuBygAs4CEiXOMHN8ohaKAPOPvR3OJ8l%20B7ygHNzy9o4tfL2HIht8IG928ExgWSgOQQYEewHGwhgYFoAHcYABZODsAA8QRC6AA5MZce4%20tjqDchuEjmRxuF0MY%20s9qjl2BBbsMIpgZi56YzmTBBHdvAKfFMQHlaOU8iBnuEsrkCnEgA)):

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"a","type":"foo"},{"id":2,"name":"b","type":"bar"},{"id":3,"name":"c","type":"fizz"},{"id":4,"name":"d","type":"foo"}]

const result = Array.from(
  arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
    const type = o.type
    if(!acc.has(type)) acc.set(type, [])

    acc.get(type).push(o)

    return acc
  }, new Map()),
  ([type, groups]) => ({ type, groups })
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: well done sir much appreciated, I didnt think to approach this using reduce and creating a type based of the original arr via its first object will help me in many instances with this current feature

*you-are-the-best-nacho-libre.gif*

Comment: You're welcome :) I've added another variation on the same idea.